# What about SEO in one page website with ajax loaded content?

Tags: seo, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One page portfolio - Effect on SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14031/one-page-portfolio-effect-on-seo)

As my title I'd like to build a website with just one input text for searching restaurants and I would like to load via ajax in the same page the resultst in a list.

After the list is loaded if you click on one row for Restaurant details it load via ajax all the Restaurant details.

what about SEO in a website structure like this?

There is a way to index every single restaurant?

I'm pretty new in SEO and every comment will be for sure important to me in order to understand and learn more about it.

Cheers

Comment: How many restaurants/pages are you considering? Is it not possible to build an alternative navigation structure perhaps based on location?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the content is going to be loaded dynamically using Ajax you still will need some static html for the layout and structure.

When you say `I'd like to build a website with just one input text for searching restaurants` do you mean that is like the layout of Google just one input field in the center of the page ?

Even if you want to keep the layout very minimalistic, try to embed the keyword that you are focusing on the title, url (if you can), h1, h2 and on the first paragraph of the content. You can use some jQuery to make a toggle button which hides the content from the user unless they click it. The content could be an introduction about the service and the benefits that it brings to the table, that way you help SEO and you also help the users.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a system for this:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Other search engines may or may not implement such a system.